# JMeter can't send data to influxdb in docker environment

Tags: testing, docker, jmeter, influxdb, grafana

I want to use influxdb and grafana in docker environment to show time-series data from jmeter.

I tried the set up from this post: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/
and the only difference here is, I'm a docker environment. So I set up the influxdb configuration from the information given from docker hub(https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb/):
[image]

I change the configuration file like this:
[image]

and type:
"$ docker run -p 8086:8086 \
      -v $PWD/influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:ro \
      influxdb -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf"
in termianl,

And finally when I want to get the data from localhost:8083, enter database jemeter, and type"SHOW MEASUREMETNS", nothing shows there.
What might be the reason here?

Answer (score 0):

port 8086 is for HTTP API to add the data. If you use graphite protocol, port 2003 should be enabled and mapped.

`docker run -p 8086:8086 -p 2003:2003 ...`

will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check jmeter backendlistner settings. Check here IP of InfluxDb Container and port. it shouldn't be localhost.